# Not able to remove/update arrow annotation in Pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've tried implementing everything I could find regarding removing or updating arrows/annotations/patches and nothing seems to work.

Here are the important parts of the code:

```
for i in xrange(lim):

    if 'arrowprops' in kwargs:
        kwap = kwargs.pop('arrowprops')
        ap = {'patchA':text} # Ensure arrow is clipped by the text
        ap.update(kwap) # Add arrowprops from kwargs

    bboxes = get_bboxes(texts, r, (1, 1), ax) #Will give error if you didn't put arrows
    for j, (bbox, text) in enumerate(zip(bboxes, texts)):
        drawArrow = ax.annotate("", # Add an arrow from the text to the point
                xy = (orig_xy[j]),
                xytext=get_midpoint(bbox),
                arrowprops=ap,
                *args, **kwargs) 

    drawArrow.remove() #removed arrows otherwise old arrows remain
    plt.draw()
```

This is from lines 524 to 645 from here [https://github.com/Santosh-Gupta/adjustText/blob/master/adjustText/**init**.py](https://github.com/Santosh-Gupta/adjustText/blob/master/adjustText/__init__.py)

Each time it goes into the loop, the location of the arrow end points are different, but just draws a new arrow without removing the old arrow, so the images look like this

https://snag.gy/bDERmr.jpg

I saw that the .remove() is the proper way to remove an annotation, and it's not updated until the plot is drawn again so that's why I put plt.draw()

This is bit hard to debug/test/isolate because it's a python package that I am trying to alter. But perhaps there are some other work-arounds that I can try and implement.

Comment: Are you sure the indendation is correct? If you want to remove every arrow, `drawArrow.remove()` would need to be inside the  loop. Else, you only remove the last one.

Comment: So `drawArrow.remove()` needs to be inside the `for j, (bbox, text) in enumerate(zip(bboxes, texts)):` loop, otherwise it'll only remove the last arrow in that loop? In that case, is there another way to remove the arrows? My first idea is to make drawArrow an array, ie `drawArrow[i]` but this may not be the most computationally efficient solution especially at larger numbers.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but for sure adding arrows and later remove them is very inefficient. In constrast, having objects stored in lists in per so not inefficient at all.

Comment: The package I am trying to alter is one for moving text annotations so that they do not overlap, with arrows going from the data point to it's text. It does this in a iterative process, so at each step, the text placement and arrow from the text to the point change. Before there was an option to save the plot at each intermediate step, but it did not include the arrows. I am trying to include the arrows in each saved plot, but including the arrows has resulting in the plot saving all arrows from all steps, so I am looking to only include arrows from the particular step.

Comment: I would suggest that you produce a [mcve] of a code where you use `adjustText` and which shows the issue. This would make it easier to localize the problem.